# Error to get Json with a SUM in Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the Following problem i cant get the Json return beacuse i have the following error code:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: Precio in **/var/www/html/cafe/Consumido.php** on line **14**

This is my Code

```
<?php
// Include confi.php
include_once('confi.php');
$fecha = "'" . date('Y-m-d')."%"."'";
$uid = isset($_GET['uid']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']) :  "";
    if(!empty($uid)){
    $qur = mysql_query("SELECT Sum(comprasdetalle.Precio) FROM compras INNER JOIN comprasdetalle ON comprasdetalle.idCompras = compras.idCompras WHERE  compras.CafeEmpleadoCodigo = $uid AND   compras.Date LIKE $fecha
        GROUP BY
        comprasdetalle.Precio;");
    $result =array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qur))
    {
        extract($r);
        $result = array("Precio" => $Precio); 
    }
    $json = array($result);
}else{
    $json = array("'status'" => 0, "msg" => "'User ID not define'");
}
@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);?>
```

I have done this without the SUM and it works but if i Add the Sum it give a error detailed above

Can you please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just found the error and fixed it like this:

```
    <?php
// Include confi.php
include_once('confi.php');
$fecha = "'" . date('Y-m-d')."%"."'";
$uid = isset($_GET['uid']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']) :  "";
    if(!empty($uid)){
    $qur = mysql_query("SELECT Sum(comprasdetalle.Precio) as Precio FROM compras INNER JOIN comprasdetalle ON comprasdetalle.idCompras = compras.idCompras WHERE  compras.CafeEmpleadoCodigo = $uid AND   compras.Date LIKE $fecha
        GROUP BY
        comprasdetalle.Precio;");
    $result =array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qur))
    {
        extract($r);
        $result = array("Precio" => $Precio); 
    }
    $json = array($result);
}else{
    $json = array("'status'" => 0, "msg" => "'User ID not define'");
}
@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);?>
```

just needed to add a name to the field

Thanks